# What is an array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, dojo

I only wanted to know what is an array.

An ***array*** is a collection of items of same data type stored at contiguous memory locations.

This is what I got

Just in simple words

Comment: Welcome! If you haven't already, would you mind taking some time to read ["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541)? I think you will find it useful in adjusting your self-expectations to be in line with the rest of the community's.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are like boxes : If you declare an array of integer with 5 in size, you can have have 5 integer in it. If you wish to select the first item, you have to take the 0, then the second is 1, the next is 2 etc... And the last is 4 (because you begin at 0). To put it simple, the last integer of your array is always : the size of your array (here is 5) minus one (last integer is 4).

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level, an array is just **data that scripts can understand as separated**.

Lets say I made an array of numbers in PHP like this:

```
$arrayornumbers = Array(10,21,32,44);
```

It isn't read like a string of text '10,21,32,44' but instead, it's known that they're 4 separate numbers.

I could then loop through them and add 4 to each of them individually:

```
foreach($arrayofnumbers as $number){
echo $number + 4;
}
```

An array can be much more advanced, with nested arrays, or in other words, arrays inside arrays, which I like to think of as folders with files in. Also you can use them for any data type, not just numbers. Hope this helps.